# Expanding the power (x+y)ⁿ into a sum - how to compute coefficients?

Tags: javascript, math

The power **(x+y)<sup>n</sup>** can be expanded into a sum of terms of the form **a<sub>i</sub> x<sup>b</sup> y<sup>c</sup>** where the coefficient **a<sub>i</sub>** of each term is a positive integer.

I'm looking for a function that computes the `Array` of all these coefficients **a<sub>i</sub>** given **n**.

**Example 1:** For n = 1: **(x+y)<sup>1</sup> = 1x + 1y** => return `[1, 1]`

**Example 2:** For n = 2: **(x+y)<sup>2</sup> = 1x<sup>2</sup> + 2xy + 1y<sup>2</sup>** => return `[1, 2, 1]`

For n = 3 the result would be `[1, 3, 3, 1]` and so on.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:html-helper]? *"Refers to the `HtmlHelper` class for ASP.NET MVC views."* Please don't tag-spam. I've removed the tag for you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder To follow up on what you said, please don't just give us a request. We aren't a code writing service. If you've got a question, show us your effort and we'll be glad to help

Comment: There's no built-in JavaScript function that does that. Details in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript). You'll need to write one. If you run into trouble writing it, post a question about *that* (including your code).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation of this could be:

```js
function Tartaglia(n) {
  var row = new Array(2);
  row[0] = [1];
  for (i=1; i<= n; i++) {
    if (i > 1) {
      row[0] = row[1];
    }
    row[1] = new Array(i+1);
    row[1][0] = 1;
    row[1][i] = 1;
    for (j=1; j<i; j++){
      row[1][j] = row[0][j-1] + row[0][j];
    }
  }
  return row[1];
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('compute').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var n = document.getElementById('iVal').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(Tartaglia(n), 4, 4);
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<input id="iVal" type="number">
<button id="compute">Compute</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suffice it to build a pascal triangle and return the last row :

```
function powMatrix(n){
    var result = [];
    result[0] = [1];
    result[1] = [1,1];
    for (var row = 2; row < n+1; row++){
      result[row] = [1];
      for (var col = 1; col <= row -1; col++){
          result[row][col] = result[row-1][col] + result[row-1][col-1];
          result[row].push(1);
      }
    }
    return result[n];
}
console.log(powMatrix(3)); //-->[ 1, 3, 3, 1 ]
console.log(powMatrix(4)); //-->[ 1, 4, 6, 4, 1 ]
console.log(powMatrix(5)); //-->[ 1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can exploit fact that the coefficients **a<sub>i</sub>** are - according to the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) - binomial coefficients. Those can easily be computed in **O(n)** as:

```js
function binomial_coeffs(n) {
  var half = n >> 1, coeffs = new Array(n + 1);
  coeffs[0] = coeffs[n] = 1;
  for (var i = 1, coef = 1; i <= half; ++i) {
    coeffs[n - i] = coeffs[i] = coef *= (n - i + 1) / i;
  }
  return coeffs;
}

console.log(...binomial_coeffs(0));  // 1
console.log(...binomial_coeffs(1));  // 1 1
console.log(...binomial_coeffs(2));  // 1 2 1
console.log(...binomial_coeffs(3));  // 1 3 3 1
console.log(...binomial_coeffs(10)); // 1 10 45 120 210 252 210 120 45 10 1
```